# Can't access a public class of DataAccess layer from an another class of Business Logic Layer

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, data-access-layer, business-logic

Why public classes can't be called from an another class? It's like I've done the same thing before in a .NET project but this time I'm not being able to call an another class of DataAccess Layer from a class in BusinessLogic Layer?? is there anything I can do?

whenever I am trying to call the class of Data Access Layer it's giving error :

The type or namespace "ClassName"( In my case ReportRepository) could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Are you referencing the library the class is in? are you able to post the code?

Comment: yes I did reference the library in the class but still nothing happened. it's still not getting the class

Comment: using Sify.DataAccess;
using Sify.DataAccess.ReportRepository;
using Sify.ASI.DataAccess.ReportRepository;
using System.Data;

namespace Sify.BusinessLogic.ReportBAL
{
   public  class RDLCReportBAL
    {

       Report2Repository new1 = new Report2Repository();

       public DataTable DistrictReportGenerate(int DistrictId)
       {
           return new1.DistrictReportGenerate1(DistrictId);
       }
    }
}        //This is  the code. I'm not being able to access Report2Repository class though it's a public class of DataAccess.ReportRepository

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a recommended approach, but you could "new" up the dependancy in the constructor for now.

```
using Sify.DataAccess;
using Sify.DataAccess.ReportRepository;
using Sify.ASI.DataAccess.ReportRepository;
using System.Data;
namespace Sify.BusinessLogic.ReportBAL
{
    public class RDLCReportBAL
    {
        private Report2Repository new1;
        public RDLCReportBAL()
        {
            new1 = new Report2Repository();
        }
        
        public DataTable DistrictReportGenerate(int DistrictId)
        {
            return new1.DistrictReportGenerate1(DistrictId);
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach to look into once you have this working is *Constructor Injection* using a **DI container** like AutoFac, but possibly further down the learning path.

Here's a basic example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/842869/Repository-Pattern-using-Dependency-Injection-Auto